# My first is like an octopus

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> My first is like an octopus, her moves are one to envy.
>
> My second is a language whose, land spans far and plenty.
>
> My third is not a minor now, divided by a penny.
>
> And as a bonus - find my secret, shared among age twenty.

**Who am I?**

---

You must explain how each part of the riddle relates to the answer

**Edit:**

Hint #1

> The first does not actually resemble an octopus

Hint #2

> Both *friend* and *foe* (except for one other) envy her moves

Hint #3

> There is a number somewhere in the riddle

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a nudge in the right direction, I figured out the third hint! For those interested, I had several alternate interpretations.

My first:

> is a **queen** – the chess piece that can move in eight different directions (Hint #1). All of the foes (enemy pieces) envy her for being the most powerful enemy, and all of the other friends (pieces on the same side) envy her as being the most powerful piece on their side, except the pawn which can become a queen (Hint #2).

My second:

> is **english**, the language spoken in most of the lands on earth.

My third:

> **1800** since 18 is the age [in most of the world] when you are no longer a minor, and dividing by a penny (1/100) gives us 1800.

Therefore I think the answer is:

> **Queen Victoria of England** who lived in the 1800s. For the bonus, "Victoria's Secret" is named after Queen Victoria of England (and twenty year old men purchase Victoria's secret for their girlfriends: a secret shared among these twenty year olds?)

Comment: Yes, you got the correct final answer! However it cannot be accepted just yet as you needed to provide the correct explanation for each part. Parts 1 and 2 are correct, however Parts 3 and the last part haven't been correctly explained yet (although your explanation for the third probably makes about as much sense as mine tbh :D ).

Comment: Here are some hints to guide you:
rot13(Ntr bs znwbevgl vf abg avargrra va zbfg pbhagevrf. Jung vf?
'Qvivqr ol n craal' zrnaf n yvgreny zngu qvivfvba.
Jung qb lbh guvax vf ivpgbevn'f frperg?)

Comment: Considering that you intended different explanations for hints #3 and the bonus, I am surprised that I got the right answer! I'll see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Sorry, but i was looking for something else for the hints
rot13(Ntr bs znwbevgl vf 18 va zbfg bs gur jbeyq. Qvivqr ol n craal qbrf abg unir gb qb jvgu 'creprag' - vg'f na npghny zngu qvivfvba. Nyfb tbbtyr ivpgbevn'f frperg ;) naq jub ohlf gurz)

Comment: Znlor V nz bireguvaxvat vg, ohg jura V qvivqr 18 ol n craal, V qba'g haqrefgnaq jung gur erfhyg vf fhccbfrq gb zrna. V nffhzr gur tbny vf gb svther bhg gur havgf? Trggvat 18 onpx sebz 18 qvivqrq ol 1 frrzf gbb gevivny hayrff V nz zvfvagrecergvat craal nf orvat rdhny gb 1.

Comment: n craal vf jung senpgvba bs n qbyyne?

Comment: Yes that's it! I guess the riddle was a little to obscure

Comment: Pbby chmmyr, V pna frr zlfrys qbvat zber bs gurfr sbe sha fb gunaxf sbe cvdhvat zl vagrerfg! V xrcg nqqvat 1 lrne gb trg 19 (naq 22) jura va snpg lbh prnfr gb or n zvabe gur zbzrag lbh ghea 18. V guvax qvivqvat ol n craal pbashfrq zr sbe njuvyr, naq V jbhyq fnl gung "cre prag" vf nyfb n ernfbanoyr vagrecergngvba — gubhtu pbaarpgvat "18 cre praghel" gb Dhrra Ivpgbevn jbhyq unir orra n fgergpu